# What is the best way to modify a module in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am importing from a module. The module has a bug where when I ctrl-c to close the program, the command prompt will hang. I found the fix, and I have modified the module to fix it. That is great and all, but if I want to distribute this to a friend then i will need to include the module or else  the program will be bugged. To fix this, I created a class and inherited from the class in the module, and then rewrote the function that was bugged. Will this cause any complications in the future and is there a better alternative to this?

Here is what I am doing:

```
class ToastFix(ToastNotifier):
    def show_toast(self, title="Notification", msg="Here comes the message",
                    icon_path=None, duration=5, threaded=False):
        """Notification settings.

        :title: notification title
        :msg: notification message
        :icon_path: path to the .ico file to custom notification
        :duration: delay in seconds before notification self-destruction
        """
        if not threaded:
            self._show_toast(title, msg, icon_path, duration)
        else:
            if self.notification_active():
                # We have an active notification, let is finish so we don't spam them
                return False
            self._thread = threading.Thread(target=self._show_toast, args=(title, msg, icon_path, duration))
            self._thread.daemon = True
            self._thread.start()

        return True
```

Also a link to the module: https://github.com/jithurjacob/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications

Comment: Why don't you open a PR in the module source code to fix this upstream as well? And the wrapper you have developed is also okay as a workaround

Comment: I will do that! Are there any other better ways to solve this?